# Python: Iterate through list and remove duplicates (without using Set())

Tags: python, list

So I have a list:

```
s = ['cat','dog','cat','mouse','dog']
```

And I want to be able to iterate through the list and remove the duplicates, WITHOUT using the set() function! So for example it should remove 'cat' and position s[2] BUT keep 'cat' at position s[0]. It then needs to do the same thing for 'dog', ie. keep 'dog' at position s[1] but remove 'dog' from position s[4].

So the output is then:

```
s = ['cat','dog','mouse']
```

I have tried to use i and j as index positions in the list, and check whether the element at position i is equal to the element at position j. If so, it will remove it and increment the value of j by 1, if not then it will leave it and just increment the value of j. After the whole list has been iterated through, it will increment the value of i and then check the whole list again, for the new element. Below:

```
i = 0
j = 1
for a in range(len(s)):
    for b in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] == s[j]:
            s.remove(s[j])
            j = j + 1
        else:
            j = j + 1
    i = i + 1
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Use in instead of ==. Store them in a sepate array if that value doesn't exist in that array.

Comment: Is there any reason you need to update the list in place vs. create a new list? `l = []; for e in s: if e not in l: l.append(e)`

Comment: Another problem is that you are iterating through all the indexes up to the end of the list. If there actually are any duplicates, the list will be shorter by the time you get there, and you will get an IndexError.

Comment: Why don't you use `set` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is with "automatic" for loops - you have to be careful about using them when modifying that which you are iterating through.  Here's the proper solution:

```
def remove_dup(a):
   i = 0
   while i < len(a):
      j = i + 1
      while j < len(a):
         if a[i] == a[j]:
            del a[j]
         else:
            j += 1
      i += 1

s = ['cat','dog','cat','mouse','dog']
remove_dup(s)
print(s)

Output: ['cat', 'dog', 'mouse']
```

This solution is in-place, modifying the original array rather than creating a new one.  It also doesn't use any extra data structures.

Comment: Thanks mate! Was thinking about using a while loop, missed the part about the j, after the first while, and the list.remove() just wasn't working for me! Thanks!

Comment: Returns None for me. `List = ['94. / Date: 16 Feb, 2022 ', '95. / Date: 16 Feb, 2022 ', '96. / Date: 16 Feb, 2022 ', '97. / Date: 16 Feb, 2022 ', '98. / Date: 16 Feb, 2022 ', '99. / Date: 16 Feb, 2022 ', '100. / Date: 16 Feb, 2022 ', '101. / Date: 16 Feb, 2022 ', '102. / Date: 18 Feb, 2022 ', '103. / Date: 18 Feb, 2022 ', '103. / Date: 18 Feb, 2022 ', '103. / Date: 18 Feb, 2022 ', '103. / Date: 18 Feb, 2022 ', '103. / Date: 18 Feb, 2022 ', '103. / Date: 18 Feb, 2022 ']`

Comment: Please check that you have copied the code exactly, and are using it as I have demonstrated.  Yes, the function returns `None`: note that the function is a mutator function that modifies the list in-place, as described above.  Additionally, I would recommend against using a variable name like `List`, as that is dangerously close to the builtin keyword `list` (and is a keyword if you use the typing library).

Answer (score 6):

You can loop through the list and check if the animal has already been added.

```
s = ['cat','dog','mouse','cat','horse','bird','dog','mouse']

sNew = []
for animal in s:
    if animal not in sNew:
        sNew.append(animal)

s = sNew
```

Comment: Is there an alternative to "not in"? The purpose of my task is to understand how the sorting algorithms work, so "not in" is kind of cheating I guess.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't alter the list while you iterate over it, you'll likely either skip elements or get an `IndexError`. If you just can't use `set` use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict

>>> s = ['cat','dog','cat','mouse','dog']

>>> list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(s).keys())
['cat', 'dog', 'mouse']
```

Comment: Not OP but thank you for the answer. I'm trying to understand your code. So you can use `OrderedDict` because the list can be regarded as a dictionary with just keys but no values? What does 'fromkeys' do? Thanks.

Comment: @BowenLiu `fromkeys` creates a dictionary with the specified keys. I used an ordered dictionary because it's ordered and removes duplicate keys, we don't care about the values of the dictionary - but there's no builtin ordered set...

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation and introducing this new method. I didn't know that you can create dictionaries without value corresponding to each key. Thanks.

Comment: Note that in modern Python (CPython/PyPy 3.6, and any Python 3.7+) you can just use `dict.fromkeys` and it will run faster to boot (`dict` is insertion ordered, and `OrderedDict` isn't necessary unless you're relying on the order-changing methods or order-sensitive comparisons). There's also no need to call `.keys()` (on any version of Python); `dict`s are already iterables of their keys, so `list(dict.fromkeys(s))` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you wouldn't use a set, but here is an alternative. Iterate over your original list, placing each element into a new list if it is not already in the new list. Example:

```
l = []
s = ['dog', 'cat', 'cat', 'mouse', 'dog']

for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i] not in l:
        l.append(s[i])
```

Now:

```
>>> s
['dog', 'cat', 'mouse']
```

Comment: More canonical would be just to iterate of the list `s` vs. indices.

Comment: Very true. It would likely be more Pythonic.

Comment: Is there an alternative to "not in"? The purpose of my task is to understand how the sorting algorithms work, so "not in" is kind of cheating I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one line solution:

```
s = ['dog', 'cat', 'cat', 'mouse', 'dog']   

answer = [animal for idx, animal in enumerate(s) if a not in s[:idx]]
```

And you'll see:

```
>>> answer
['cat', 'dog', 'mouse']
```

Answer (score -1):

```py
s = ['cat','dog','cat','mouse','dog']
duplicates = []

for animal in s:
  if s.count(animal) > 1:
    if animal not in duplicates:
      duplicates.append(animal)
print(duplicates)
```

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: This adds nothing that the other answers didn't already cover, and is actually wrong, as it doesn't keep anything *unless* it's duplicated (it does reduce duplicates to a single copy, but eliminating the non-duplicates is wrong). For the OP's case for instance, they expect to see `'mouse'` as the final element in the result, but you exclude it because it only appears once.

Answer (score -2):

Here is only by Type-Casting,

```py
s = ['cat','dog','cat','mouse','dog']

l = list(set(s)) 

print(l)
```

Comment: The OP's question specifically excluded the use of `set`; if they hadn't, this would be fine, but it was also be incredibly obvious (the restriction in the question is why noone else posted it).