# How do we remove duplicates from an iterator and put it in sorted order?

Tags: python

How do we remove duplicates from an iterator and put it in sorted order?

Sample input:

```
it = iter(["black", "aqua", "aqua", "black", "black", "blue", "aqua", "blue", "fuchsia", "gray", "gray", "green", "green", "aqua", "lime", "lime"])
```

Expected output:

```
it = iter(["aqua", "black", "blue", "fuchsia", "gray", "green", "lime",])
```

Similar questions have been asked before:

- someone previously asked [how to remove duplicates from an iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32012878/iterator-object-for-removing-duplicates-in-python) about implementing the iterator protocol and their own class with `__iter__` and `__next__` methods defined.
- someone previously asked [how to remove duplicates from an iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43623304/python-iterate-through-list-and-remove-duplicates-without-using-set) restricted to *not* using Python's built-in `set` class.

There are almost no restrictions on this question other than it be written in Python.

Answer (score 0):

```python
# oit ..... output iterator
# iit ..... input iterator  
oit = sorted(set(iit))
```

Comment: `oit` is a list, not an iterator. You'll need to wrap it in `iter` if you want an iterator i.e. `oit = iter(sorted(set(iit)))`